# Bluetooth won't pair Xubuntu 11.10

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth, lenovo

I'm running a Lenovo Thinkcentre M55e running Xubuntu 11.10, I bought a bluetooth adapter dongle. Inserted dongle into USB and it recognizes it but it won't ' Pair " with my phone. I used this same method @ work on my Thinkcentre with XP on it and it worked no problem. Used the same passcodes on both machines. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well I have tried that several different times, it always seem to fail to pair with device. Maybe it's due to me wanting to pair my smart phone with my Thinkcentre? I haven't tried my bluetooth headset yet. But thanks for responding soo fast!

Answer (score 3):

### Connecting to a Bluetooth device using blueman-manager:

To connect to a new bluetooth device in XFCE **blueman-manager** is installed by default and can be run either by right-click on the panel bluetooth icon or by typing `blueman-manager` in a terminal.

[image]

Select *Adapter->Search* to find any bluetooth device present. Put your device in **pair mode** (consult your device's manual if you are not sure how to do this) and proceed:

[image]

Right click on the appropriate device and select *Pair...* in the popup menu.

[image]

Enter your authentication PIN code here (`0000` is the default for a headset).

**Still we do not know what service we want the device to be connected with.**

[image]

Choose the appropriate service (depicted for *Headset* here, choose *"Browse Device...* or *"Send a File..."* for data transmission in case your device supports this) from the right-click menu. This should present you a window similar to the following indicating the device is ready. The Bluetooth icon in the panel will be marked by a green dot in addition.

[image]

---

**Note:** For some devices that were connected to another machine in between we may have to remove the device first before we can pair and reconnect it again, even if the device is known to Blueman.