# Why can't my pc and iPhone find each other via Bluetooth?

Tags: 11.10, bluetooth, iphone

I've got Bluetooth enabled on both the computer and the iPhone, and both devices can see my Bluetooth headset so this confirms that Bluetooth itself works.

But when I let either device look for other devices, they find nothing (when the headset is off).

I'm using 11.10 with all the latest updates. I have not installed any special or additional Bluetooth software; only whatever Ubuntu provides by default.

Comment: It looks like [this answer might be useful.][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/108535/bluetooth-wont-pair-xubuntu-11-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the problem lays with the iPhone as Apple only supports headsets to pair with an iPhone and not Pc's. Can you connect to ur headset with your pc, because then the problem lays with the iPhone for sure..

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes, my headset connects. Are you saying I am the first and only person wanting to connect an iPhone to Ubuntu? I doubt that.

Comment: pretty shure bluetooth for the iphone is only for "audio stream" and no data transfer, when you jailbreak the iphone it is all possible with "AirBlue". More info on this apple site : http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647 (only audio support)